$C^1$ function $f>0$ on $\Bbb R$ satisfies $f ^ { \prime } ( x ) = f ( x - 1 )$.

$C^1$ function $f>0$ on $\Bbb R$ satisfies $f ^ { \prime } ( x ) = f ( x - 1 )$. How to find $f$?

It is easy to deduce that $f(-\infty)=0, f(+\infty)=+\infty$. Then...
If $f'(x)=f(1-x)$, then $f''(x)=-f'(1-x)=f(x)$. It is easy. But here $f'(x)=f(x-1)$...

Maybe the values of f are set on a unit interval [a,b] then in the next unit interval $f(x)=f(b)+\int_b^x f(x-1)dx,x\in[b,b+1]$.

This answer is about the existence of solutions in a more or less explicit form, not about proving that those solutions are the full set.
Try $f(x)=C\exp(\lambda x)$ then $f$ is a solution if and only if $\lambda=\exp(-\lambda),$ which has exactly one real solution for $\lambda.$ The constant $C>0$ can be chosen arbitrarily.
An appropriate combination of conjugate complex solutions could also work. If $\lambda=a+bi$ then the condition becomes $a=\exp(-a)\cos(b),$ $b=-\exp(-a)\sin(b).$ However, while such solutions might satisfy the delayed differential equation, they are unlikely to be positive.
